# Facebook Ads API - Ad Acount

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I try to add a ad account by graph API but alway error : "(#275) Cannot determine the target object for this request. Currently supported objects include ad account, business account and associated objects." . Help me , thanks so much

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwU4p.png

Comment: please add your code snapshot also.

Comment: Yes, I changed it

Comment: Please refer this link contain detailed description. your request are getting failed during validation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup

Comment: My mean Ad a ad account API

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account